# onLoad and onunload events not firing

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/javascript ">
<body onLoad="timeTracker._recordStartTime();">
<body onunload ="timeTracker._recordEndTime(); timeTracker._track(pageTracker);"
</script>
```

I am trying to use this code to record the time interval between load and unload of a page.

Unfortunately, it does not work. Why?

Comment: First of all you place html tags inside javascript block...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may only specify one `<body>` tag. Also, it's not possible in HTML to specify plain HTML tags inside script tags.

Either add the handler through JavaScript, or merge the attributes in one `<body>`-tag. JavaScript is case-sensitive, so you should use `window.unload` (lowercase) instead of `window.onLoad`.

Use:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    timeTracker._recordStartTime();
};
window.onunload = function() {
    timeTracker._recordEndTime();
    timeTracker._track(pageTracker);
};
</script>
```

*OR* (without `<script>` tags):

```
<body onLoad="timeTracker._recordStartTime();" onunload ="timeTracker._recordEndTime(); timeTracker._track(pageTracker);">
```